# The background color isn't stretching the entire width of screen

Tags: html, css

I am in the middle of making an about section for my website then I encountered an issue where the section isn't covering the entire width of the page and nothing I found on other posts is working for me. I am using bootstrap5 if that helps.

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    
}

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    padding: 1rem 8rem;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.navbar-nav {
    padding-right: 9%;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}



#navbarSupportedContent > ul > li:nth-child(n) > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding: 0 0.8rem;
}

#navbarSupportedContent > ul > li:nth-child(n) > a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

#navbarSupportedContent > button {
    outline: none;
    background: rgb(197, 190, 190);;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.4rem 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

#navbarSupportedContent > button:hover {
    background: grey;
}

.mid {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.mid video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero {
    position: relative;
}

.hero h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.mid .hero p {
    width: 55%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    padding: 1.1rem;
}

.mid .hero a {
    background: rgb(197, 190, 190);;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.mid .hero a:hover {
    background: grey;
}

.about {
    background:#000;

}

.about .text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: auto;
}

.about .text h2 {
    color: #F7F5F4;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2.7rem;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.about .text p {
    color: #F7F5F4;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Talk Tech Teen Tech</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Talk Tech Teen Tech</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Listen</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Specs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Premium Techy</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                  
                </ul>

                  <button class="btn btn-outline text-dark" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        <div class="mid">
          <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="images/mic.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source>
          </video>
          <div class="hero text-center">
            <h2 class="text-light display-4">Talk Tech Teen Tech</h2>
            <p class="text-light mx-auto">This podcast talks about tech but through the eyes of grade school teens to get a different approach on the bleeding-edge of technology</p>
            <a class= text-dark href="#">Start Listening</a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="about container py-5 my-5 mx-auto">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="img col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 pt-5 pb-5">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="images/mic.png">
        </div>
        <div class="text col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 pt-5 pb-5">
          <h2>About Us</h2>
          <p>Talk Tech Teen Tech is a podcast created by teens, made for the masses. In this podcast we talk about the bleeding edge of technology but through a teens perspective and what we think tech should be about and how companies handle technology. We talk about products from all sorts of companies (Apple, Samsung, OnePlus, Xiomi, Dell, Microsoft etc.). Our goal was to introduce another prespective of technology into the web and also to influence others that you don't need to be 30 to create a tech podcast, and with minimal gear you can create an amazing podcast!</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>





<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the Result**

[image: As you can see their are white bars on the sides as well as the bottom]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping your container with the section will most likely fix the problem.

Instead of writing this;

```
<section class="about container py-5 my-5 mx-auto">
```

try this:

```
<section class="about py-5 my-5">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
```

You probably have a margin set around your container

Also your `about` styles should be set to `width: 100%`

Comment: Wow thank you so much man it fixed it can you explain why this is an issue though just so I can have a better understanding?

Comment: You're using a bootstrap container here. It has a max-width applied to it. This means every styles applied to `.about` will have the same max width, since it's applied to the same element.

Instead, what you should always be doing is wrapping the container class within the section.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `container` class limits the max-width to be less than the full page width, see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%;` to the about section CSS as you did to the CSS of `.mid`.
If this does not help, you can try `width: 100% !important;`, `width: 100vw;` and `width: 100vw !important;`.

Answer (score -1):

Elements scale to the width of their parent. Is the element you're trying to draw the background on inside a body container that has some padding?